# Should I explicitly use the httpClientFactory class as a recommendation when creating and using typed http clients and DI in .NET 6?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

I am using NSwag to create typed http clients with interfaces and registering them with DI using AddHttpClient() and injecting them where they need to be used in calling APIs.

I read about some limitations of the httpclient class such as socket exhaustion & not detecting dns changes and the recommendation to use httpClientFactory and its CreateClient method to create httpclients to alleviate these limitations.

I haven't used the httpClientFactory in a new app that I started working on.
It's using .NET 6 and my question is.. Is httpClientFactory still a recommended way to use explicitly or is it used implicitly in DI because of the use of AddHttpClient() and I don't have to worry about those limitations? I didn't see a clear direction on how to use typed clients, or http clients in general, and whether .NET 6 has introduced improvements in this area.

Comment: There's one gotcha with `AddHttpClient<T>` that you should be aware of an it is discussed in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36067) issue report.

Answer (score 2):

- `HttpClient` can be injected only inside typed clients
- For other usages `IHttpClientFactory` is required

As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#httpclient-and-lifetime-management) state for either case underlying infrastructure (`HttpMessageHandler`) is managed by the framework so in general you don't need to worry about it (unlike when creating and managing `HttpClients` manually which could lead to incorrect disposal).

Using typed clients registered via `HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.AddHttpClient<TClient>` [handles](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,157) `IHttpClientFactory` for you. When adding typed client internally [`AddTypedClientCore`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs,78287356ca909681) is called which [registers resolver via `AddTypedClientCore`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs,40566b7f63997713), which uses `IHttpClientFactory`:

```cs
IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory = s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
HttpClient httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(builder.Name);
 
ITypedHttpClientFactory<TClient> typedClientFactory = s.GetRequiredService<ITypedHttpClientFactory<TClient>>();
return typedClientFactory.CreateClient(httpClient);
```

Related:

- [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)